# showing predefined file at File Chooser Option in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

So, i am showing a file chooser dialog using:

```
    JFileChooser c = new JFileChooser();
    int rVal = c.showSaveDialog(this);

    if (rVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
      saveFile((c.getCurrentDirectory().toString() + "/" + c.getSelectedFile().getName()), "data to be saved");
    }
```

It works fine, but problem is user himself has to write a file name at the file prompt where file name is to be provided or he can select a file from file listing so that it can be overwritten.

I want to know is there any way that the file chooser text box already shows the users suggested file name so that he simply clicks on save and it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call [setSelectedFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setSelectedFile%28java.io.File%29) method before showing the dialog.

Comment: it does not show the selected file at the prompt. Only whatever name users provides, it saves the file with the name provided in setSelectedFile option

Comment: sorry my appologies, it works. i had a mistake that's why it didn't show... thank you for the answer